# A set of fields for one property entity in Symfony 2

Tags: forms, symfony

My `Product` entity has the following structure:

```
private $id;

private $title;

/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
 * @JoinColumn(name="cat_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $category;
```

`Category` have nested structure. And each level of nesting is shown in 5 separate fields:

[image]

In class form code, I solve it in this way:

```
$builder
->add('cat_1', 'entity', array(
    ...
    'query_builder' => function() { return someSelectLogic1(); }
))
->add('cat_2', 'entity', array(
    ...
    'query_builder' => function() { return someSelectLogic2(); }
))
->add('cat_3', 'entity', array(
    ...
    'query_builder' => function() { return someSelectLogic3(); }
))
->add('cat_4', 'entity', array(
    ...
    'query_builder' => function() { return someSelectLogic4(); }
))
->add('cat_5', 'entity', array(
    ...
    'query_builder' => function() { return someSelectLogic5(); }
))
```

Now I need to know which field is filled in the last turn and pass the value of that field in the entity property.

In all that I do not like:

- complex logic to determine which field with category was filled at the end
- each of these fields is not tied to the entity `'mapped' => false`

1) **What the right way to organize code of my form?**

2) **And is there a way to bring these fields into a separate class which will deal with the logic of determining which category was chosen in the end?**

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the following:

**1) Create a new custom form field type and put all those `entity` in there.**

This process is not much different from ordinary creation of form type. Just enclose those fields in it's own `buildForm()` and that should do the trick. [Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html).

**2) Mark all those `entity` fields with property "`property_path` => `false`".**

Clearly you wont be storing these values inside your model.

**3) Add two more fields: `chosen` and `lastOne`.**

Now, this might be tricky: I would either set the `chosen` to `text` type (basically, generic type) or would use `entity` as well. If you go for `entity` you would need to include all possible answers from **all entity fields**. As for the `lastOne` set it to `text` as it will reflect which field (by name) was selected last.

Either way, those two fields will be invisible. Don't forget to set `property_path` to `false` for `lastOne` field.

**4) Finally, add `ValueTransformer` ([docs](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html)) which will contain logic to "see" which field was selected last.**

*Now, I dealt with it only once and don't understand it just quite yet, so your best bet would be trial and error with examples from official docs, unfortunately*.

What basically you should do is to, within value-transformer, read the value of field `lastOne`. This will give you the name of field which was selected last. Then, using that value, read the actual last value selected. Last, set that value (object, if you've went for `entity` type, or it's ID otherwise) to `chosen` field.

That should basically do the thing.

As for the JS, I don't know if you're using any framework but I will assume jQuery. You will need to set `lastOne` field as your selecting items in your form.

```
$(function(){
    $('#myform').find('select').on('change', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest('form').find('#__ID_OF_YOUR_LASTONE_FIELD').val($this.attr('name'));
    });
});
```

I'm sorry I cannot provide you with code samples for `PHP` right now. It's a bit late here and will do my best to further update this answer tomorrow.